# Move table row after mouse click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I'm new to jQuery and my task is:
I have table and when I select a row I should get a small pop-up with the row elements sticks to the mouse pointer  and I should be able to be drop in a div container, when dropped on the container I should display the row details.

So I had some Googling but couldn't find any plugin for my work, I could find plugins that can traverse within the table but not out of the table, so I started working myself.

I have created a simple table and a dialog, when I click on the dialog the popup should open and when mouse is up the dialog should be closed/hidden. I'm able to move the div message when the mouse is clicked on the table but not able to hide the div message as that event is not getting fired, can anyone please help me in this:
Or I will very happy if there is a ready plugin or any better option for the problem...

```
   <html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="css/print.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen,print" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen,print" href="css/styledForm.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen,print" href="css/filterBox.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen,print" href="css/jquery.multiselect.css" />    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/folder-tree-static.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/context-menu.css" type="text/css" />    
    
    <script src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>
    
    <script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.droppable.js"></script>    
    <script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.sortable.js"></script>
<!--    <script src="js/jqDnR.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dragging.js"></script>-->
    <title>
        Draggable & Droppable Demo
    </title>
    <style>
        #demo_leftcontainer
        {
            float: left;
            width: 30%;
            height: 100%;
            vertical-align: middle;         
        }
        #demo_rightcontainer
        {
            float: right;
        }

}        
#simple_dialog
{
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #bcd5e6;
    text-align: center;
}
    </style>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var flag = 0;
        function position (using)
        {
        $('#simple_dialog').position({
            of: $('#devices_table'),
            my: "left top",
            at: "left top",
            offset: $('#div_message').html(),
            collision: "none none"
        })
        }

        $('#devices_table').mousedown(function(e, ui){
        $('#simple_dialog').show();
        position(e);

        })
        $('#devices_table').mousemove(function(e){
        var elem = $('#devices_table');
        var off = elem.offset();
        X_value = e.pageX - off.left;
        Y_value = e.pageY - off.top;
        $('#div_message').html( X_value+ ' ' + Y_value);
        position(e);
        })    
        $('#devices_table').mouseup(function(e){
        $('#simple_dialog').hide();
        })


        })
</script>    
    

    <body>
        <div id="flag_content">Flag value : </div>
        <div id="div_message" >Positions</div>
        <div id="demo_leftcontainer">
            MAHESH
        </div>
        <div id="demo_rightcontainer">
            <table id="devices_table" width="900px" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>COL1</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Membership</th>
                    <th>Devices</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>ANS</td>
                    <td>SDFD-1</td>                    
                    <td>Direct</td>
                    <td>N/A</td>                                        
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>FODF</td>
                    <td>SDFDF-2</td>                    
                    <td>Direct</td>
                    <td>N/A</td>                                        
                </tr>                
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
    <div id="simple_dialog" style="display: none">
        SIMPLE DIALOG
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: mousemoveR instead of mousemove in line 71

Answer (score 0):

You should check your syntax. There are extra  `{ }`s  in the style .

Also you should:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
});
```

I don't understand want to achieve but if you want to learn, it won't help if someone just writes your code. You should better explain WHAT you want to happen and WHEN.

I don't that working with selections it's a good idea. You should think more in clicking html tags. For example

```
$('td').click(function(){
    
    var text = $(this).text();
});
```

will give you the text in a cell which you can place inside a div by its id:

```
$('td').click(function(){
    
    var text = $(this).text();
    $('#divdialog').text(text);
});
```

And you can use jQuery UI (http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) to turn that div into a dialog window

```
$(#divdialog).dialog()
```

Comment: I have a table right with username as one row and a treeview on left, user should be able to drag the rows and drop onto the treeview, when dropped I should be able to add the username into the treeview. While dragging the I should show a small notes for selected row, notes will be according to the number of rows selected, but the notes should be shown until I drop the row. Hope you understand the task, this is one of the requirement in our project so asking, it is not for self learning.